# How to apply CSS styles to links that appear in table headers?

Tags: css

I would like to apply CSS styles to links that appear in column headers in my web page.  I have added the following to my CSS:

```
thead tr td a { color: White; }
```

However, my links are still the standard blue (purple when followed) color.

A link in a column header is an anchor tag embedding in a `td` tag embedded in a `tr` tag which is embedded in a `thead` tag, right?

Why isn't my CSS producing the desired result?

**Update:**
Interestingly, this doesn't work either: all links on the page are still blue and purple.

```
a { color: white; }
a:hover { color: white; }
a:visited { color: white; }
a:active { color: white; }
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML markup - ideally a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: @mikevoermans Agreed, this question is unanswerable without the HTML.

Comment: We need to see the page, because that isn't normal browser behaviour

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with browser caching.  It seems that with IE8, "refresh" doesn't always mean "refresh".

Comment: I was once served beer at an IE restaurant by Bill Gates.  I asked for my beer to be refilled.  He picked up the half-empty glass and walked into the kitchen.  Five minutes later, he re-emerged with the same half-empty glass and placed it on the bar in front of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
thead tr td a { color: white; }
thead tr td a:hover { color: white; }
thead tr td a:visited { color: white; }
thead tr td a:active { color: white; }
```

See this live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/sdah4/)

To remove the underline include `text-decoration: none;` in the first tag

If that still doesn't work try using `!important` after each one

Comment: That should work. Are you sure your CSS is coupled to your html page correctly?

Comment: All my CSS was working fine until I tried to make the links in column headers white.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page

Comment: I got it fixed.  It turned out to be a caching problem with my browser.  It seems that with the newer versions of IE that it keeps stuff even after you click to delete "temporary internet files".  They may as well call them "permanent internet files."

Comment: try hitting ctrl+f5 when doing your refresh.